# NodeJS worker threads pools

Tags: node.js, multithreading

Have a question for those with more experience with worker threads here..

I have been doing some testing with worker threads and have a question on how they work, or maybe how they should work.

I am using a worker thread pool called piscina, this has been setup and appears to be working. 'Appears' to is the key..

Here is my scenario. I have a 'workers.js' file that has a 'longer' run script ( this is for testing and purposefully a long loop)

When running it, it does what it should, the main EL is still open to process other tasks etc, however what I have noticed is that there only appears to be 1 worker.

What I mean by that, is subsequent request to that route seem to get queued up, so the request don't run in parallel, instead, waits until the first worker finished, then goes on to the next.

What I would like to have happen, is that each request fires off a new 'worker' (to a point, then place them in the que) right now we have the app running in containers, so if the CPU or Mem gets too high, it should push traffic to the other container etc.

Now with that being said, we would still like to have the workers spawn out with each request as to not bottleneck the inbound request to that 'page'.

Again, maybe I'm not understanding this properly but anyone with more experience with workers that would help me out would be greatly appreciated.

*** edit with code ***

Route:
*Route contains imports of piscina library

```
router.get('/:error?', auth("3","edit"),function(req,res){

    console.log('running')


    let piscina = new Piscina({
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'worker.js'),
        minThreads:5
    });

    const result = piscina.run({accountID:req.session.AccountID,cID:req.session.cID,cCode:req.session.cCode}).then(data =>{
```

console.log(date)

```
    })

});
```

Worker file

```
module.exports = async({accountID,cID,cCode}) => {
    
    const n = 10000000000;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        
    }

    return 'finished';
})
```

After running the loop, it simply return back the 'finished' string, as noted that works, however if I hit the page in multiple tabs they do not all finish at the same time, instead, lets say tab 1 takes 7 seconds to finish, tab 2 and 3 tak 14, then 21 etc.

**Note: The variables we are passing to the worker have no use RN, its just a loop that we run for testing to verify the flow**

Comment: Is this a coding question or a general advice? You question includes no code and seems for me more like "pleas explain that" instead of "i have a problem with my code"

Comment: Hi Marc. Well, I guess its more of a general question on the inner workings of the workerthread in general and if they should be run in parallel. My searching seems to indicate that they should be able to do this, however what I am seeing, this does not seem to be the case, hence the question, is this expected behavior. I can for sure post the code I am running, however it does work, just not sure if this is expected behavior. If not, I would like to get to the bottom of why this is happening, if it is, then I can move on know those limitations.

Comment: Breake it down to the absolute minimalistic -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it.

Comment: I added the code we are running to provide more context

Comment: Why are you creating in every request a new Piscina instance? Create one instance and for every request call `piscina.run(...)`. Then you should be able to handle 5 requests simultaneously and the 6+ request should be queued.

Comment: Hmm, the docs seem a bit light on this TBH, they setup has the new as part of the request so I'm not sure if that is the idea, a new worker with each request or a shared worker for 'said' request. I did try breaking it out and saw some weird issues where the request seemed to stack, so request 1 took 7 seconds, request 2 took 14, then 21. Seems odd.  I guess I'll keep trying on this one. Have some question out on their main hub so see if I can get some clarity. Thanks for the responses though, gives me some things to chew on.